# Running scripts during git commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to call/start another process/command prior to git finishing the commit?

My co-workers and I share computers, and for any given commit, it could be one of a number of people doing the work. The problem is that it is a hassle to remember to set the git username prior to doing the commit, and so it never happens. What I would like is a way to have a prompt come up when "git commit" is called that would ask for the current user and then set the git user to that value. Setting up a commit script is one way to do this, but most people directly call git, so that wouldn't work.

Is this possible to do? Without forking git that is. :)

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: You share computers - but couldn't you have your own clones of the repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write a simple script to prompt for the name and set it accordingly, you could then use that script in a [pre-commit hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit), and Git will call it for you just before making a commit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could take advantage of the git `pre-commit` hook? http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html

Answer (score 0):

create a ".gitconfig" file in your home directory (locally).

Containing the following:

```
[user]
    name = Your Name Comes Here
    email = you@yourdomain.example.com
```

Comment: The problem is getting people to actually fill it in. :)